# Terraform: ConcurrentUpdateException: You already have a pending update to an Auto Scaling resource

Tags: aws-lambda, autoscaling, terraform-provider-aws

I'm trying to configure Application Auto Scaling to manage provisioned concurrency in a lambda function via Terraform. Sometimes I get the following exception when running **apply**:

```
Error creating application autoscaling target: ConcurrentUpdateException: You already have a pending update to an Auto Scaling resource.
    status code: 400, request id: dd93d5d3-314c-11ea-aeb2-d9246c0fa0b9

  on autoscaling.tf line 1, in resource "aws_appautoscaling_target" "autoscaling-lambda-target":
   1: resource "aws_appautoscaling_target" "autoscaling-lambda-target" {
```

I know this error occurs **if you request an update to an Application Auto Scaling resource that already has a pending update**. As I said it happens *sometimes*. How could I avoid this 100%?

my *autoscaling.tf* (since there are many lambdas, it runs for each one)

```
resource "aws_appautoscaling_target" "lambda-target" {

  depends_on = [
    aws_lambda_alias.alias-qa
  ]
  for_each = aws_lambda_function.lambda-function

  max_capacity = local.lambda_functions[each.key].max 
  min_capacity = local.lambda_functions[each.key].min 
  resource_id = "function:${each.value.function_name}:${var.stage}"
  scalable_dimension = "lambda:function:ProvisionedConcurrency"
  service_namespace = "lambda"
}
```

Comment: Do you know what the concurrent update is?  Is it something else in the same Terraform update, or something else outside terraform causing it?  You might want to check cloudtrail around the time you're running the stack.  Filter by:
Event source: autoscaling.amazonaws.com
This will return all API calls to autoscaling

Answer (score 0):

Usually, you have one scaling target with one or more autoscaling policies. You get that error when you run the aws_appautoscaling_target more than once against an ECS service or lambda. Check the loops you have, the issue is there for sure

Answer (score -1):

You could try setting `-parallelism=1` so it does not try to do multiple operations at the same time, this will slow down the overall deployment though.